# How to center Navbar-Brand middle of link-item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got an issue with my navigation menu.

What I want is my brand is in the middle of my navigation link.

Example
`Home | product | Company Logo(this is my brand) | about us | contact us`.

When I open in small device I want the company logo stay at the current position or middle of navbar and others link item (`home|product|about us|contact us`) display when I click the toggle icon.

Below is my source code :

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
                      </li>
                          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
                          </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </div>
                          </li> 


        <a class="narbar-brand">Company Name</a><!-- I want this company name stay at top when I open my website via small device -->

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Suppport and Downloads</a>
                  </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Partners</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                      </li>
            </ul>
            <!--<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>-->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

below is the sample navigation in big/small screen device. I want the Company Name appear on small device

current problem:
[image: big]
[image: small]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do use media query for this and create two nav brand elements

```css
a.navbar-brand.center {
  display: none;
}


@media (max-width: 990px) {
  
  a.navbar-brand {
        display:none;
  }
  
  a.navbar-brand.center {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 10px;
  }
    
  li.nav-item {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand center" href="#">Your brand</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your brand</a>
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Redline Welcome to stackoverflow. glad your problem has been solved. it'd be great if you accept my answer so the community members know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Using below custom css you can achieve

```css
.navbar-header .navbar-brand{
  display:none;
}
.nav-item .navbar-brand{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-header .navbar-brand{
    display:block;
  }
  .nav-item .navbar-brand{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
                      </li>
                          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
                          </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </div>
                          </li> 


        <!-- I want this company name stay at top when I open my website via small device -->

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="navbar-brand">Company Name</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Suppport and Downloads</a>
                  </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Partners</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                      </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: already try but my naviggation link item gone for both small and big screen